# Assigning new variables that are created in increments easier

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
for(int x = 0; x < 24; x++) 
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    {
        switch(lvl)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                maptileset0[y][x] = maptileset1[y][x];
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                maptileset0[y][x] = maptileset2[y][x];
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                maptileset0[y][x] = maptileset3[y][x];
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                maptileset0[y][x] = maptileset4[y][x];
                break;
            }
            case 5:
            {
                maptileset0[y][x] = maptileset5[y][x];
                break;
            }
            case 6:
            {
                maptileset0[y][x] = maptileset6[y][x];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hello, I am relatively new to cocos2d and programming, but what I am doing is assigning the map array which is full of ints to the main array so that the scene can load it, is there a better or cleaner way of doing this? Is there a way to assign the array without having to add a new case every time when I create a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the other `maptileset` an `std::vector`, and assign to `other_maptileset[lvl][y][x]`.